# ZMAP gurus: Getting the response body or Is it just banner grabbing?

Tags: nmap, port-scanning

Im trying to use zgrab/zmap to scan an IP list for a JSON endpoint and id like to collect more than just banner data (also the JSON response) - is this possible? it looks like zgrab just collects HTTP banner data.

What I have so far:

```
zmap -p 80 --output-fields=* 23.226.228.12 | ./zgrab --port 80 --data=./my-req --output-file=banners.json
```